# how to place an div tag for datalist control

Tags: asp.net, css

i have  a  datalist control where i  displaying images have  (6 colums  * 5  rows)
. right now i am  showing entire thing in   a page.  but  i need  to  fix the height   to 
 300px  .  and  do the scrolling thing  so that  i can  show  the  3,4  5  row  of the datalist control

does anyone know  the  css  how  to  fix  this  issue

thank  you

Answer (score 0):

Assuming the wrapping `<div>` element has the id `myDiv`:

```
#myDiv {
  height: 300px;
  overflow: auto;
}
```

Comment: i have  an scrool image: which is  an ARROW type  image.  i need  to  embed that image  for  the scroll. how  to  solve this  issue
 thanks  for the replay

Comment: Sounds to me like you want some kind of custom/virtual scrollbar. Personally, I would prefer a standard scrollbar, but if you really want to change it: http://www.hesido.com/web.php?page=customscrollbar

Answer (score 0):

Off the top of my head, I'd wrap a div around your images, and set the height in the style element of that div to 300px.  Then set the overflow (also in the style element) to scroll

```
<div style="height: 300px; overflow: auto">
... your images
</div>
```

edited following jorn's comment.

Comment: `overflow: scroll` will put scrollbars in both directions, even if they are not needed, right?

Comment: yeah i'll buy that, auto is a better option here.

Comment: thanks  for the replay adrianos
  can u  show   write  the css how to do it. as  i  am new in  css.
 where i need   to get  my scrol image
  thank  you

Comment: Not sure what you mean by scroll image.

If you mean the scroll bar for the div, 'overflow: auto' will automatically add it when the content of the div (your images) is greater than 300px.